# Delete files modified in last n hours from a folder

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I have a folder where I sometimes get a few big files after doing some work. I delete them manually. I know it's possible to delete them after 1 day or more but I would like to delete them if they have been modified in the last few hours.

There are files in that folder I do NOT want to delete and they all have similar yet unpredictable filenames. I can't just use del to delete the newest ones, I have to rely on modify date.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /some/dir -type f -mmin -<minutes old> -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

This finds all items under `/some/dir` that are files and are less than `<minutes old>` minutes old, and removes them.  Don't forget the `-` before the number of minutes.  Also, if mmin doesn't do the trick, try cmin.

Comment: If you're going to assume GNU find, this can be simplified to `find /some/dir -type f -mmin -<minutes old> -delete`. Run it first without the `-delete` option to show what it would delete. With POSIX `find`, `find /some/dir -type f -mmin -<minutes old> -exec rm {} +`. But this requires Unix utilities which are not bundled with Windows.

Comment: Doh.  Did the 'windows 7' tag get added after I answered?  I didn't see it if not.  I wasn't aware of -delete.  To be frank I'm not a fan of -delete and -exec arguments to find; they seem like bloatware, and the escaping that -exec always required offended my delicate sensibilities.  Still, additional knowledge is good; Thank you.

Comment: @slartibartfast: I added the Windows tag because the question body mentioned Windows. `-exec` is POSIX, whereas `-print0` is not. (Mind, `-mmin` isn't POSIX either, so my objection wasn't justified.) Escaping `find` output for `xargs` is hard unless you have `-print0`; I like `-exec ... +` a lot better, and it doesn't require any escaping.

Comment: Personal preference.  I just think find+xargs is more unix-y (in the philosophical sense, not POSIX/non-POSIX).  I also recommend grep -Z and possibly tar --null.  (Note also that xargs can do controlled parallelism with -P)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the Windows Explorer can sort by modification time, so you could do that and select the files that were modified in the desired time range.

[slartibartfast](https://superuser.com/questions/178606/delete-files-modified-in-last-n-hours-from-a-folder/178607#178607) has given an answer that assumes you have Unix-like utilities installed. On Windows, this could be [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [GNU Win32 utilities](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [Microsoft Windows SFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX) or [UWIN](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/tools/uwin/). If you install one of these, make sure to use its `find` and not the unrelated native Windows command.

Comment: I would first like to get this to work without installing any extra software and after im sure i can't be done i will try out some of the mentioned utilities.

You said:
"IIRC the Windows Explorer can sort by modification time, so you could do that and select the files that were modified in the desired time range."

How do do this?

Comment: @TMRW: Open the directory in Explorer. Select “Details” in the “Display” menu (the name may be different in your version of Windows). Then click on the header of the date&time column to sort by date&time.

Comment: Yeah that's the manual way.I'm looking for an automated way via cmd.